# Correct location for .au sound clip file for Eclipse Java applet

Tags: java, audio, applet

This issue should be simple although apparently I'm missing it.
I have a Java applet with images and a sound clip.
All of the images display correctly and they are in the /bin file.

However, the sound clip is also in the /bin file and it isn't playing at all.

The questions are: 1)  Is this code snippet for the sound clip correctly formatted?

mySound = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "OnPoint.au");

and 2)  Where should the sound clip be located, isn't it the /bin folder?

Below is the code, please advise, thanks!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
```

import java.util.*;  // Timer is in this library

```
public class bTrainAnimation extends Applet
{
private Image trainAndBush[];    // "Image" is inherited
private int totalImages = 17,    // total number of images in array
currentImage = 0,                // set current image array subscript to 0
sleepTime = 500;                 //  milliseconds to sleep
MediaTracker myImageTracker;     // "MediaTracker" is inherited
Timer myTimer;                // "Timer" is inherited
private AudioClip mySound;    // "AudioClip" is a inherited

public void init()
{
 // load the images when the applet begins executing
setSize(400,400);
mySound = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "OnPoint.au");
myTimer = new Timer(true);
myTimer.schedule(
    new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run() // "run" is action performed by timer task
        {
            repaint(); 
                    }
    }
           ,0,sleepTime); // global VAR "sleepTime" = 500 milliseconds

// create array of all the images in slide show
  trainAndBush = new Image[ totalImages ];    // global VAR "totalImages" = 17 images
  myImageTracker = new MediaTracker( this ); 
  for( int i = 0; i < trainAndBush.length; i++ )
   {
   trainAndBush[i] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), // load an image in an applet 
     "Hill" + (i + 1 ) + ".jpg" );  

 // track loading image
 myImageTracker.addImage(trainAndBush[i], i);
   }

    try
     {
       catch ( InterruptedException e ){}
       mySound.play();
     }

 public void start(Graphics g)
 {
g.drawImage(trainAndBush[0],50,50,300,300, this );
currentImage = 1;       
 public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
{
if (myImageTracker.checkID(currentImage, true))
          {
      g.drawImage(trainAndBush[ currentImage ],50,50,300,300, this );
      if (currentImage == 0 )
        trainAndBush[ totalImages -1].flush();

        else trainAndBush [ currentImage -1].flush();
        currentImage = ++currentImage % totalImages;
      }
     else
            postEvent( new Event( this, Event.MOUSE_ENTER, ""));
       }
   }
 // override update to eliminate flicker
  public void update(Graphics g)
   {
  paint( g );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to read your code with the formatting, but I'll do my best to answer. (If you update/edit your question, I'll try to update/edit my answer):

I am not sure where you are getting the idea of the "bin" directory. If that's working for images, then something else is going on.

Now, it's been a while since I've done this, but my interpretation of the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) is:

getDocumentBase() gives you the URL of the containing page, so if your applet is contained in http://example.com/folder/hello.html, that's what getDocumentBase() gives you.

If your audio is located in

http://example.com/folder/audio/OnPoint.au

then your code would look like this:

mySound = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase().parent().child("audio"), "OnPoint.au")

Note that Java's URL class does NOT have parent() and child() functions (that would be too easy!), I just made that up and included it for explanatory purposes.

Comment: Hello Bjorn,  thank you for the response.  I apologize for the formatting, it's from a professor's "animation" template.  Also, the "bin" directory is where the .class files are, and I've read online that that is where the audio file is supposed to be located....is this correct?  Anyway, the next question that comes to me is: Where do I find the "URL of the containing page?"  I am running this program as a Java applet directly from Eclipse.

Comment: UPDATE:  I have the answer!  While the code above is "rough" it does work now.  The problem was that I didn't actually convert the .mp3 file to .au, I just changed the extension name.  So, I used an online converter tool by Convert.Files, added the converted file to the /bin folder, and I am rolling.  Let me know your thoughts Bjorn, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like eclipse is doing some file management for you: moving things to the right place and all so that when it runs it can all be found. Just a guess. Glad you got it working, though.